# Why doesn't an onMouseOver action appear to be working in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, function-call

I'm having an issue with this function call for some reason, and don't know why (it gets called every time):

```
box = document.getElementById("object");
box.onmouseover=function();
```

Comment: Try to specify the function name itself, don't call it (remove the brackets). Also, function name should not be `function`, it's reserved keyword in JS. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using function as the generic term.  Can you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAv2E/1/)**. `hoverhandler` is function-handler (just as the example), that works every time when `mouseover` event is fired on `div-two`. To show that it works, it changes the background color of `div-one`. Hope this example will help you.

Comment: I was forgetting to move my mouse, I thought it would auto check it on load :(